# How to get an element's value in jquery?

Tags: jquery, function

How can I get the value of `data-toggle` inside function `load_data(id)`? It's been really messy lately. It just don't work whatever I try.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" id="faq_list">

  <li  data-type='parent'>
    <a href="javascript:;"  data-toggle="a77" onClick="load_data(1)">General</a>
    <div id="target_1" class="subdata"></div>
  </li>

  <li  data-type='parent'>
    <a href="javascript:;"  data-toggle="b99" onClick="load_data(4)">Orders</a>
    <div id="target_4" class="subdata"></div>
  </li>

  <li  data-type='parent'>
    <a href="javascript:;"  data-toggle="cAB" onClick="load_data(3)">Problems</a>
    <div id="target_3" class="subdata"></div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

How can I get `data-toggle` tag's value inside function `load_data(id)`?

Comment: `$(this).data("toggle")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solutions if you WANT.

**Change this :**

```
<a href="javascript:;"  data-toggle="a77" onClick="load_data(1)">General</a>
```

**into**

```
<a href="javascript:;"  data-toggle="a77" onClick="load_data(1, this.attributes[1])">General</a>
 // this.attributes[1] --> capture element atribute at index 1, 
 // in this case is "data-toggle" 
 // same goes to another a element
```

**javascript**

```
function load_data(no, dataToggle){
  console.log(dataToggle.value);    
}
```

===================== OR =======================

**change this :**

```
 <a href="javascript:;"  data-toggle="a77" onClick="load_data(1)">General</a>
```

**into**

```
<a href="javascript:;"  data-toggle="a77" onClick="load_data(1, this)">General</a>
```

**then in load_data function :**

```
function load_data(no, elem){   
  console.log($(elem).data('toggle'));    
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/Lsc7sdjg/1/)**

Comment: Thanks - "this" works fine inside function parameter